# Knockout.js equivalent to Kendo MVVM nested binding

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

We are currently using Kendo UI and its integrated MVVM framework to control the forms in our application on the client side (e.g. input validation, disabling/enabling form fields based on conditions). As we hit some limitations of the Kendo MVVM framework, we plan to switch to Knockout/Knockout-Kendo.js.

As our forms are highly dynamic, one critical feature for us are Kendo MVVM's nested bindings. They allow us to monitor fields of dynamically composed forms which aren't known up-front:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview#bindings

Looking at the knockout.js docs, I couldn't find an equivalent there. How can I emulate a similar api in knockout.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would use the [with](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) or [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding to handle nested structures.  This can also be done with the [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding.  In fact, you can even dynamically choose which template to use by doing something like [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_dynamically_choosing_which_template_is_used).

For your situation, using a dynamic template name seems like it might be appropriate.  You would create templates for the various "types" of forms that you are dealing with and then use the item's "type" to determine which template to use.  Here is a link to an article that I wrote when the feature first was added to KO: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html.

Comment: thanks for the hints! unfortunately I can't use client-side templating, because the user can override the form rendering with his own templates on the server side. However, I managed to achieve the desired result with an id-based dictionary of viewmodels, e.g. {formfieldId1: <formfield1Model>,...}. This allows me to use "namespaced" bindings (data-bind="visible: formfieldId1.visible")

There is just one question left: how can I propagate model changes "downwards" the form hierarchy? (e.g. a fieldset is disabled -> all contained formfields should be disabled)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you can get a lot of power from using the `$root`, `$parent`, and `$parents` special variables.  These let you bind against variables in a higher scope: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html.

Comment: thanks for the hints, but I'm afraid they don't apply to my problem. I've posted a follow up question to illustrate my problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648867/knockout-js-how-to-bind-hierarchical-forms