# Knockout.js: how to bind hierarchical forms?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js under the hood of my client-side form manipulation api. Its is designed to manipulate "hierarchical" forms that are built of tabs, fieldsets (contained in tabs) and individual form controls (contained in fieldsets).

My strategy is to create a separate view model for each of these components. My question is: how can i best propagate the model state "downwards" the hierarchy? (e.g. when a tab is disabled programmatically, i also want also all contained fieldsets to be disabled and their form controls)

I've prepared a jsfiddle to sketch my first approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbuchinger/bxNKg/4/

On the dom side everything looks fine so far, but i noticed that the group's 'editable' state isn't propagated downwards to the form control's model (the `PRENAME.editable` property is still `true`, although it should be `false`). Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple approaches that could work:

1. Pass the controls that a group should govern to the group constructor.  Then, set up a subscription to the groups editable observable to propagate it to the children.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ryKpS/
2. Pass the group to each control's constructor and subscribe against the group's editable observable and update this child's editable observable (I would prefer #1 to this one, as it is nice when a child does not need to know about their parent explicitly).  Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qRCq4/
3. Use pub/sub to synchronize the values.  I have a small library of extensions here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox.  You can have your group publish a message when its editable property changes and then have the children subscribe to that topic.  That way the parent and child do not need direct references to each other.  You would probably need to consider the topic to see if it would need to incorporate a group id or something to make it unique.  Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HC2jx/

Comment: thanks a lot for this thorough and really valuable answer! Finally I went with solution 3 (PubSub), as there are no inter-dependencies between the view models. knockout-postbox is a really useful plugin!